# Remove SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy from DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, transactions, ef-core-7.0, resiliency

I have my `IDbContextFactory<MyContext>` in my Asp.Net Core App registered using `RetryOnFailure()` on my `Startup.cs` which adds a `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy`.

However for a specific action in my app, I need to use my own `System.TransactionScope` so I can have a distributed transaction across multiple databases on multiple servers.

Is it possible to remove the `SqlServerRetryingExecutionStrategy` from a `DbContext` instance that I got from my `IDbContextFactory<MyContext>.CreateDbContext()`?

Comment: register different factory that creates context without this option?